# Android onFocusChangeListener on System Alert view

Tags: android, focus, android-view

I set a `onFocusChangedListener` on a view and used `windowmanager` and added the TYPE_`SYSTEM`_ALERT view with `addView()`

However, `onFocusChanged` is never called even when *I pulled down the notification panel covering the view*. I'm pretty sure the view is not focused because the home key is no longer disabled when panel is down.

Any ideas?